# MVC 4 razor alert box

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When i m showing alert, page dissapears. How can i prevent page to be dissapeared while showing alertbox.
I m printing alert as follows:

```
    @{
        if (ViewData["result"] == "false")
        {
            ViewData["result"] = null;
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                alert("Invalid user name or password");
            </script>
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes previous problem was solved. bt this alertbox problem still persists

Answer (score 0):

On my machine your code is working fine but if it's not working for you then

Try this :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   if ('@ViewData["result"]' == "false"){
  '@ViewData["result"]' = null;
   alert("Invalid user name or password");
   }
   else{ alert("Valid user name or password"); }
</script>
```

Comment: your answer still not works, even it is not displaying alertbox.

Comment: it gives Keys -> count = 1 and [0] = "result" and it has the value as i assigned from my model class

Comment: @Mayank...just see value you are sending from controller it should be "false" with quotes...

Comment: @Mayank..i think in your problem control is not going in if statement try using else statement also...see updated answer..